# Production Angular/nodejs app with cPanel. Node.js app error?

Tags: node.js, angular, deployment, cpanel, production

I have deployed an angular app via cPanel (compiled with command 'ng build --prod="true"') and its currently live: https://nathankeogh.com

It also uses node.js backend which is running on cPanel. App Startup file is "server.js".

I have imported data from MySQL database with data etc. on cPanel also. (Used command "sed -e 's/utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g' -i myfilename.sql" to get arround unknown collation error.)

My prod.envrionment.ts file currently points the ApiURL to "httpS://nathankeogh.com".

I have updated the node.js application on cPanel, with the name and credentials for the database on cPanel.

When accessing the website, It loads the login page as expected but as you can see, getting an Internal server error (unknown) in chrome's console and data will not post/get:
[image: error]

The development version is working as expected.

**Further development:** When hovering over the "error" text in the chrome console, it shows a full error output:

[image]

"Web application could not be started". I believe its a cPanel node application error:
[image]

Following this, a cPanel error states an issue with server.js file line 7? or 22?. ("app.use('/accounts', require('./accounts/accounts.controller'));") **Can anyone identify what is wrong the server.js file causing the issue?**

Any help in identifying the problem or advice is very much appreciated. Thank you.

node.js cPanel config:
[image]

Server.js:

```
require('rootpath')();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const errorHandler = require('_middleware/error-handler');

const multer = require('multer')
//const upload = multer({ dest: 'images/' })
var fileExtension = require('file-extension')

//app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/uploaded-files'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// allow cors requests from any origin and with credentials
app.use(cors({ origin: (origin, callback) => callback(null, true), credentials: true }));

// api routes
app.use('/accounts', require('./accounts/accounts.controller'));
app.use('/lab-swaps', require('./lab-swaps/lab-swaps.controller'));

// swagger docs route
app.use('/api-docs', require('_helpers/swagger'));

// global error handler
app.use(errorHandler);

// start server
const port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? (process.env.PORT || 80) : 4000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server listening on port ' + port));

// Basic Get Route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'Server Started!' });
});

var storage = multer.diskStorage({

    // Setting directory on disk to save uploaded files
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploaded-files')
    },

    // Setting name of file saved
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + fileExtension(file.originalname))
    }
})

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        // Setting Image Size Limit to 2MBs
        fileSize: 2000000
    },
    fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
            //Error 
            cb(new Error('Please upload JPG and PNG images only!'))
        }
        //Success 
        cb(undefined, true)
    }
})

app.post('/uploadedImages', upload.single('uploadedImage'), (req, res, next) => {
    const file = req.file
    console.log(req);
    if (!file) {
        const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
        error.httpStatusCode = 400
        return next(error)
    }
    res.status(200).send({
        statusCode: 200,
        status: 'success',
        uploadedFile: file
    })

}, (error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(400).send({
        error: error.message
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you share the logs of the Node.js app?

Comment: @PádraigGalvin Sorry for the late reply, I have updated the question with image of Node.js app error and more, after digging deeper. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info @Nath94. The server.js7:22 means line 7, column (i.e. character) 22. So, it seems to indicate that there is an issue with the `require`. I also notice that in the cPanel screenshot, it says you are using Node.js version 10 which is not very recent. Are you sure this is the same version you are using locally?

Comment: @PádraigGalvin Thank you very much for your reply.
I don't see a reason for the error there as the "_middleware/error-handler" file is present. I can try without it later, thank you!

But the node.js version you mentioned, I'm embarrassingly running 6.14.10 locally (used command "npm -v" in VS code terminal to check).

Should I try to run version 6.17.1 in cPanel? (its the closest version available to the local version)

If that doesn't work I'm guessing I should try to update node to the latest version? 16.x.x?

Thank you so much again for your reply.

Comment: 6.14 is your NPM version! Use `node -v` to check which version of Node.js you are running locally. If you are working on a new project, I would recommend using the current LTS version 16.

Comment: @PádraigGalvin Thank you again. Yes that was a massive mistake, locally I'm running node v14.15.4. I will adjust the cPanel config accordingly.

If not working ill update locally and see how it goes.

Comment: Also, instead of using "rootpath"  you should just use relative paths `const errorHandler = require('./_middleware/error-handler');`, it's more conventional.

Comment: @PádraigGalvin Thank you very much, implementing your change moved the error onto the "accounts.controller" file. Ill investigate from here. If you want to create an answer I will mark it correct. Cheers!

Comment: Sure, I've added an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rootpath` library does not seem well maintained, so it may be causing issues.

Remove it and use relative paths instead.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const errorHandler = require('./_middleware/error-handler');
 
const multer = require('multer');
```

Relative paths are more conventional, so you will avoid confusing future developers working on your code, and you will avoid [potential issues](https://github.com/fabriziomoscon/rootpath/issues/5) with your editor.